# Combining columns in a dataframe each with partial information

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large data set which used different coding schemes for the same variables over different time periods. The coding in each time period is represented as a column with values during the year it was active and NA everywhere else.

I was able to "combine" them by using nested ifelse commands together with dplyr's mutate [see edit below], but I am running into a problem using ifelse to do something slightly different. I want to code a new variable based on whether ANY of the previous variables meets a condition. But for some reason, the ifelse construct below does not work.

MWE:

```
library("dplyr")
library("magrittr")
df <- data.frame(id = 1:12, year = c(rep(1995, 5), rep(1996, 5), rep(1997, 2)), varA = c("A","C","A","C","B",rep(NA,7)), varB = c(rep(NA,5),"B","A","C","A","B",rep(NA,2)))
df %>% mutate(varC = ifelse(varA == "C" | varB == "C", "C", "D"))
```

Output:

```
> df
   id year varA varB varC
1   1 1995    A <NA> <NA>
2   2 1995    C <NA>    C
3   3 1995    A <NA> <NA>
4   4 1995    C <NA>    C
5   5 1995    B <NA> <NA>
6   6 1996 <NA>    B <NA>
7   7 1996 <NA>    A <NA>
8   8 1996 <NA>    C    C
9   9 1996 <NA>    A <NA>
10 10 1996 <NA>    B <NA>
11 11 1997 <NA> <NA> <NA>
12 12 1997 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

If I don't use the `|` operator, and test against only varA, it will come out with the results as expected, but it will only apply to those years that varA is not NA.

Output:

```
> df %<>% mutate(varC = ifelse(varA == "C", "C", "D"))
> df
   id year varA varB varC
1   1 1995    A <NA>    D
2   2 1995    C <NA>    C
3   3 1995    A <NA>    D
4   4 1995    C <NA>    C
5   5 1995    B <NA>    D
6   6 1996 <NA>    B <NA>
7   7 1996 <NA>    A <NA>
8   8 1996 <NA>    C <NA>
9   9 1996 <NA>    A <NA>
10 10 1996 <NA>    B <NA>
11 11 1997 <NA> <NA> <NA>
12 12 1997 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Desired output:

```
> df
   id year varA varB varC
1   1 1995    A <NA>    D
2   2 1995    C <NA>    C
3   3 1995    A <NA>    D
4   4 1995    C <NA>    C
5   5 1995    B <NA>    D
6   6 1996 <NA>    B    D
7   7 1996 <NA>    A    D
8   8 1996 <NA>    C    C
9   9 1996 <NA>    A    D
10 10 1996 <NA>    B    D
11 11 1997 <NA> <NA> <NA>
12 12 1997 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

How do I get what I'm looking for?

To make this question more applicable to a wider audience, and to learn from this situation, it would be great have an explanation as to what is happening with the comparison using `|` that causes it not to work as expected. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is what I meant by successfully combining them with nested ifelses

```
> df %>% mutate(varC = ifelse(year == 1995, as.character(varA), 
+                             ifelse(year == 1996, as.character(varB), NA)))
   id year varA varB varC
1   1 1995    A <NA>    A
2   2 1995    C <NA>    C
3   3 1995    A <NA>    A
4   4 1995    C <NA>    C
5   5 1995    B <NA>    B
6   6 1996 <NA>    B    B
7   7 1996 <NA>    A    A
8   8 1996 <NA>    C    C
9   9 1996 <NA>    A    A
10 10 1996 <NA>    B    B
11 11 1997 <NA> <NA> <NA>
12 12 1997 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Look at the output of `df$varA == "C" | df$varB == "C"`

Comment: Huh. I shoulda thought of checking that. I couldn't do it with my original data set (1 mil+ observations) but with the MWE it was doable. Thanks!

Question still stands about how to fix it, though.

Comment: watch that `NA=="C"` returns `NA`, while `NA %in% "C"` is `FALSE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R has this annoying tendency where the logical value of a condition that involves NA is just NA, rather than true or false.
i.e. NA>0 = NA rather than FALSE

NA interacts with TRUE just like false does. i.e. TRUE|NA = TRUE. TRUE&NA = NA.

Interestingly, it also interacts with FALSE as if it was TRUE. i.e. FALSE|NA=NA. FALSE&NA=FALSE

In fact, NA is like a logical value between TRUE and FALSE. e.g. NA|TRUE|FALSE = TRUE.

So here's a way to hack this:

```
ifelse((varA=='C'&!is.na(varA))|(varB=='C'&!is.na(varB))
```

How do we interpret this? On the left side of the OR, we have the following: If varA is NA, then we have NA&FALSE. Since NA is one step above FALSE in the hierarchy of logicals, the & is going to force the whole thing to be FALSE. Otherwise, if varA is not NA but it's not 'C', you'll have FALSE&TRUE which gives FALSE as you want. Otherwise, if it's 'C', they're both true. Same goes for the thing on the right of the OR.

When using a condition that involves x, but x can be NA, I like to use 
((condition for x)&!is.na(x)) to completely rule out the NA output and force the TRUE or FALSE values in the situations I want.

EDIT: I just remembered that you want an NA output if they're both NA. This doesn't end up doing it, so that's my bad. Unless you're okay with a 'D' output when they're both NA.

EDIT2: This should output the NAs as you want:

```
ifelse(is.na(varA)&is.na(varB), NA, ifelse((varA=='C'&!is.na(varA))|(varB=='C'&!is.na(varB)), 'C','D'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The behavior of NA in the comparisons with True and False actually do make sense when you think of NA as being an "unknown" value. TRUE | NA will always be true, likewise FALSE & NA will always be false, no matter what NA turns out to be. Makes for some frustrating behaviour though

Answer (score 1):

Per @Khashaa comment.  This should do the trick and get you to the desired output.

```
df %>%
  mutate(varC = ifelse(is.na(varA) & is.na(varB), NA, 
                       ifelse(varA %in% "C" | varB %in% "C", "C", "D")))
```

Comment: Now my only problem is that in my real dataset I have 6 of these comparisons, so I end up having to type them out twice, once through for the is.na and again for the %in%... but it works, so I'm happy. Been struggling with this all day!

Comment: `==` should be faster than `%in%`. since you are checking only for one string.